# Regex group match using shell

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I am trying to match a pattern and set that as a variable.

I have a file with many "value=key". I want to find the value for key "fizz".
In the file I have this string

```
fizz="something_cool"
```

I try to parse it as:

```
cat file | grep fizz="(.*)"
```

I was thinking it would give me the group output, and then I would be able to use `$1` to select it.

I also play with escaping characters and `sed` and `awk`. But I could not manage to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable extended regex for using unescaped `(` and `)` and quote pattern properly to make it:

```
grep -E 'fizz="(.*)"' file
```

However `awk` might be better choice here since it will do both search and filter in same command.

You may just use:

```
awk -F= '$1 == "fizz" {gsub(/"/, "", $2); print $2}' file
```

```
something_cool
```

Comment: Yes. I needed to tweak it a bit but this fixed the problem at hand. Thank you.